# Print ZonedDateTime exactly as it is parsed

Tags: java-8, zoneddatetime

I have a date string in a format:

`String date = 2014-05-05T05:05:00.000
ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC");`

the above prints:

`2014-05-05T05:05Z[UTC]`

Is there any way we can print it in the following format ?

`2014-05-05T05:05:00.000Z`

In joda time, i can easily do this:

`DateTime datetime= org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.parse(date).toDateTime(UTC)`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way we can print it in the following format ?
>
> > **String date = 2014-05-05T05:05:00.000**

You can use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()`.

```
        String date = "2014-05-05T05:05:00.000";
        ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        System.out.println(zoneDateTime);
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX").format(zoneDateTime));
```

Refrence: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: thanks, is there any way to get this printed s ZonedDateTime. This is a string actually

Comment: i tried that already, thats when i got : java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2014-05-05T05:05:00.000' could not be parsed at index 23, when i remove the X from the formatter it works , but the result is : 2014-05-05T05:05Z[UTC]

Comment: @parameswar there is no way for the code in the question to cause the error you have in your comment. The DateTimeFormatter, in the answer, is used to **format** the ZonedDateTime. This error would happen when **parsing** a ZonedDateTime. So, read the answer, correctly.

Comment: what i meant is , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX").format(zoneDateTime) is a string, which is of correct format, but i need it to be of type ZonedDateTime

Comment: I think you are putting wrong question here. read the  doc https://www.javabrahman.com/java-8/working-with-time-zones-in-java-8-zoneddatetime-zoneid-tutorial-with-examples/ and understand the usage of ZonedDateTime.Thanks